# (Probability) How to find P(A) from P(A∪B) and P(not B) when A and B are independent?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I am given that P(A∪B) = .85, and that P(not B) = .25. From this I can conclude that P(B) = 1-.25=.75, and that P(A minus B) = .1. I can't seem to figure out where to go from there though. I am trying to find P(A).

EDIT: The problem states that A and B are independent.

Comment: You can't figure it out, unless you know $A$ and $B$ are independent, or if they are disjoint. You can't even determine that $P(A\setminus B)=0.1$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews They are independent. Sorry for leaving that out. What am I able to do with this fact that will allow me to solve the problem?

Comment: You can use the fact that ${P(A\cap B)}{P(B)} = P(A|B) = P(A)$ (from independence) and $P(A) = P(A\setminus B) + P(A\cap B)$ (disjoint union) to solve for $P(A)$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: $P(A\cup B) = P(B) + P(A\setminus B)$ is true regardless of independence, because $A\cup B$ is the disjoint union of $B$ and $A\setminus B$.

Comment: @GregMartin are you suggesting using a system of equations? I can't imagine the problem was intended to go that route.

Comment: A system of two linear equations doesn't seem so horrible to me—especially when one equation is just $P(A\cap B) = \frac34P(A)$.

Comment: That's incorrect. Consider $A=\{1,2\}$ and $B=\{2,3\}$.

Comment: Whoops, yes, brain death on my part.

Comment: @GregMartin no it's not the work I'm concerned about, but knowing my professor he would not have intended the problem to be solved that way, which makes me think I may have incorrectly written down the information, or that some more formulaic method is still lurking out there.